# Bounding Box in SQL database Geodata

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table :
SuburbId int,
SubrubName varchar,
StateName varchar,
Postcode varchar,
Latitude Decimal,
Longtitude Decimal

and in MY C# I have created  code that creates a bounding box so I can search by distance.
And my stored procedure to get the subrubs is:

```
    [dbo].[Lookup] (
@MinLat     decimal(18,15),
@MaxLat     decimal(18,15),
@MinLon     decimal(18,15),
@MaxLon     decimal(18,15)
    )
   AS
  BEGIN

SELECT SuburbId, suburbName, StateName, Latitude, Longitude
FROM SuburbLookup
WHERE (Latitude >= @MinLat AND Latitude <= @MaxLat AND Longitude >= @MinLon AND Longitude <=      @MaxLon)
    END
```

My Question is.. this is a Clustered Index Scan... Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What is your clustered index for the table? Can you post the full table definition, including all indexes defined for the table?

Answer (score 0):

This type of query tends to perform quite poorly with the standard B-tree index. For better performance you can use the `geography` column type and add a [spatial index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265.aspx).

Queries such as `WHERE geography.STDistance(geography2) < number` [can use a spatial index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933796.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of links that should help.  Of course depending on the scope of you project you may already have the best solution.

That said if you care to, you can create a custom index in sql server for your locations.

[Custom Indexing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133823.aspx)

Additionally if you wanted to, you could look into Quadtrees and Quadtiles.  There is a technique where you can calculate a key via an interleaved addresses, a combination of the lat and lon pairs that, can be represented as an integer and then truncating to a base level to see how they relate to eachother.

[see more here](https://github.com/infochimps-labs/big_data_for_chimps/blob/master/11a-spatial_join.asciidoc#quadtile-practicalities)